# Ordenacao de dados C

Tags: c#, classificação

estou fazendo um trabalho de ordenacao onde o programa deve ler um arquivo texto com varias linhas e fazer a ordenacao dos valores. sao 6 arquivos, um com 10000 registros, outro com 100000 registros, outro com 1000000 registros, outro com 10000000, outro com 50000000 e outro com 100000000. O programa ta rodando e fazendo a ordenacao normal com os arquivos de 10000 registros e de 100000 registro, mas quando vou rodar o de 1000000 pra cima ele nao da nenhum tipo de erro ele simplesmente abre e fecha na mesma hora.

**código com 100000 registros:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
FILE *arq;
 int a, b, c, d, e, f;
 double linhas[100000], aux;
 int i, j;

 arq = fopen("random100000s.txt", "rt");

 if (arq == NULL) 
 {
  printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
  return;
 }
 i = 0;
 while (!feof(arq))
 {
  fscanf(arq, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
  linhas[i] = ((a*365) + (b*30) + (c) + (d*0.041667) + (e*0.00069444) + 
  (f*0.0000115741));
 i++;
 }

 for(i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
 {
  aux = linhas[i];
  for(j = i; (j > 0) && (aux < linhas[j - 1]); j--)
   linhas[j] = linhas[j - 1];
   linhas[j] = aux;
 }


 for(i = 0; i <= 100000; i++){
  printf("\n%lf", linhas[i]);
 }

 fclose(arq);
}
```

**código com 1000000 registros:**

```
    void main()
{
FILE *arq;
 int a, b, c, d, e, f;
 double linhas[1000000], aux;
 int i, j;

 arq = fopen("random1000000s.txt", "rt");

 if (arq == NULL) 
 {
  printf("Problemas na abertura do arquivo\n");
  return;
 }
 i = 0;
 while (!feof(arq))
 {
  fscanf(arq, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f);
  linhas[i] = ((a*365) + (b*30) + (c) + (d*0.041667) + (e*0.00069444) + 
  (f*0.0000115741));
 i++;
 }

 for(i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++)
 {
  aux = linhas[i];
  for(j = i; (j > 0) && (aux < linhas[j - 1]); j--)
   linhas[j] = linhas[j - 1];
   linhas[j] = aux;
 }


 for(i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++){
  printf("\n%lf", linhas[i]);
 }

 fclose(arq);
}
```

O primeiro roda e apresenta corretamente ja o segundo nao.
OBS: Os arquivos.txt estao todos com a mesma formatacao a unica diferenca é a quantidade de registros.

Alguem pode ajudar??

Comment: Começa que o loop está errado: i = 0; i <= 1000000, vai tentar ler 1000001 registros, é o famoso erro "off by one". Teria de ser i < 1000000. Se tiver dificuldade em ver o problema, teste um loop que conta até 10.

Comment: na vdd desculpa, o arq tem 1000001 de registros, tanto que o primeiro codigo sao 100001 registros e deu certo.

Comment: sera que nao pode ser o tamanho do vetor que e muito grande v[1000000]?